# Conveying "bigger than life"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

The other day I was talking about Freddie Mercury. I wanted to convey:

> Having an outrageously flamboyant stage persona he was a larger-than-life artist.

I said

> Ayant un personnage de scène outrageusement flamboyant, il était un artiste plus grand que la vie.

I was barely understood. Googling a bit I found that even the title of the (old) American film "[Bigger than life](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derri%C3%A8re_le_miroir_(film))" was changed to "Derrière le miroir".

1. What is wrong with the literal translation of "larger-than-life/bigger-than-life" and does not work in French? I know, of course, that many literal translations from English to French and vice versa (or from and to other languages for that matter) do not work; I am just wondering about this idiom in particular.
2. A phrasing like

> Ayant un personnage de scène outrageusement flamboyant, il était un artiste truculent.

would be better?

Comment: « Personne outrageusement flamboyante, sur scène *il allait au-delà de* son art. »

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal translation *plus grand que la vie* does not work indeed. It is simply one of those many idiomatic phrases than cannot be translated literally.

*Truculent* conveys indeed the same idea, but is a less common and more formal word than the English phrase *larger/bigger than life*.

Some other translations could be :

> Il avait une personnalité hors du commun/hors norme

> C'était un personnage haut en couleurs

> C'était un sacré personnage (may sound a bit outdated to young ears nowadays...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the several ways to convey the idea of larger-than-life. But what is wrong with ' plus grand que la vie'? [I understood that it does not sound ok to a native speaker.] Not being a native speaker I am wondering also from where one can find the information that 'truculent'  is considerent literary. There is two senses : https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition-truculent/. The first is obsolete; the second is exactly the meaning of larger-than-life (as you said).

Comment: There are and no there is:-)! [I made a mistake in my comment.]

Comment: *Plus grand que la vie* simply has no meaning when taken literaly in French, just like so many other idioms that cannot be translated word for word from one language to other. If you think about it, it is has no meaning if taken in the literal sense: how do you measure life ? How can you compare the size of a human with life ? And what does it imply if you are "bigger" than it ? In that sense, for once, French is more down-to-earth...

Comment: As for the language register, I did not look it up in dictionaries specifically, I made this comment based on my own experience. I remember you have already mentioned you were surprised when using some words that your French students did not understand: this may be the case here, as "truculent" is not a word used in everyday life - and I feel it is much less common than the English *bigger than life*.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much once again. I think the last two comments deserve to be added to you answer!

Comment: I will not add it because it deviates from the original question: a nice idiom you could use to describe Freddie Mercury would be *bête de scène*: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%AAte_de_sc%C3%A8ne

Comment: Ok. As you wish:-)! I still think the comment about why "plus grand que la vie simply has no meaning when taken literaly in French, just like so many other idioms that cannot be translated word for word from one language to other. If you think about it, it is has no meaning if taken in the literal sense: how do you measure life ? How can you compare the size of a human with life ? And what does it imply if you are "bigger" than it ? In that sense, for once, French is more down-to-earth" has a place in the answer considering the fact that I have a question "1. What is wrong with the literal..."

Comment: Thanks also for " bête de scène" :-)!

Comment: @Dimitris Does *μεγαλυτερο απο ζωή* make sense in Greek?

Comment: @jlliagre: In Greek one may use "larger-than-life" as it is:-)! (It requires a basic understanding of English to be understood though...)

Comment: @Dimitris Strange, I would guess most French people with a basic understanding of English or even a good level in this language wouldn't understand the meaning of *plus grand que la vie* or *larger than life* unless they have already been taught this idiom.

Comment: Looking on [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/larger+than+life.html), the translation of *larger than life* when it is used literally is *plus grand que nature.* Not being a native speaker, I don't know whether this would be understood in French if it was used metaphorically, but it seems to me it has a much better chance of being understood than *plus grand que la vie*.

Comment: I was very surprised by this, but looking closer, you can see many of the samples are actually from Quebec websites. That seems to be confirmed by the introduction to [this article](https://www.lenouvelliste.ca/opinions/plus-grand-que-nature-665fcea20f079ddc9919c2ff463d467b). I have never heard it in that sense in Europe, so I assume it is a French Canadian usage (maybe by an American influence ?). Note that *plus grand que nature* can also be used in European French, but then means "larger than the actual size" (ex: *une reproduction plus grande que nature*).

Comment: @Greg: Indeed, "larger than the actual size" is what I meant by the literal meaning of "larger than life"; I believe this is the original meaning in English, and the *personnalité flamboyante* meaning, which is much more common today, is metaphorical.